# Error while trying to create a new foreign key relationship in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

while trying to create a new foreign key constraint in SQL Server using the following syntax:

```
alter table fkTable add constraint FK_fkTable_pkTable 
foreign key (pkTable_Id) references pkTable(pkTable_Id)
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 0, Line 218 Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

this was literally the only message, there were no previous errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my tables were defined as:

```
create table pkTable (
    pkTable_Id smallint not null constraint PK_pkTable primary key identity(1,1),
    --other columns...
)

create table fkTable (
    fkTable_Id uniqueidentifier not null constraint primary key,
    pkTable_Id int not null,
    --other columns...
)
```

Where the pkTable_Id column is defined as a **smallint** on the pkTable, and **int** on the fkTable. Might seem pretty obvious but the error was not at all helpful!

Comment: 1) Your code contains incorrect synax 2) Message is clear `Column 'pkTable.pkTable_Id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'fkTable.pkTable_Id' in foreign key 'FK_fkTable_pkTable'.` See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e25c0) 3) What is the point of self answering question 5 sec after asking it?

Comment: 1) whoops, I retyped it from real code changing names and omitting stuff, will correct when back at PC 2) that is not the error I got, I only saw the message displayed in my question 3) stackoverflow offers you the opportunity to answer your own question "q&a" style, and as nothing suitable came up in my initial search I though I'd share my experience in case someone had the same problem in the future.